# How do I enable ssh access within a Docker container without copying my keys?

Tags: git, ssh, docker, ssh-keys

I want to build a Docker container that downloads a few things from private GitHub repositories (at build time!). This means that I need to provide SSH keys, but I do not want to copy them into the container, because then they would be available to everyone who has access to the container.

How can I solve this?

Basically, I'm looking for something like SSH agent forwarding, but not at container runtime, but at container build time.

Any hints?

Comment: Why not do a shell script that first download the files, then invoque docker build with a Dockerfile that do an add of those previously downloaded files?

Answer (score 0):

One simple and safe way is to download from git to your host, and then copy the downloaded files from your host to your container. No keys needed.

Get the short container id:

```
docker ps
```

Get the full container id:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' SHORT_CONTAINER_ID
```

Copy over the file (in host):

```
sudo cp path-file-host /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/FULL_CONTAINER_ID/PATH-NEW-FILE
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, as the host is OS X, and I have some modules that need to be compiled (OS X binary !== Linux binary).

Comment: Fetch them to your host, then build them in the Dockerfile.  `docker build` will upload the build context to the server.  Do you use Makefiles?  This can be made as simple as running `make` in the directory to do a `git clone $(URL) ./build/dep1` and a `docker build .`.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way of doing this is to add the Dockerfile to the root of the repo.  Clone the repo on your workstation, then do "docker build" which sends the current directory (build context) to the docker daemon.

There is little need to clone private repos *within* a Dockerfile (on the server), usually.

Comment: "There is little need to clone private repos within a Dockerfile (on the server), usually." … I'm sorry, but this is just plain wrong.

Comment: Consider for a moment that if I were wrong, your question would have been loudly answered by now.

There's a way to do what you're doing, and the way you're trying to do it isn't it.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument here, but how do you deal with private npm packages, e.g.? It's neither an option to install them on the host (wrong OS) nor to add them to source control (this is against Node.js's best practices). The same question applies to basically any private artefact that is typically installed using a package manager. And BTW: The fact that there has been no answer yet may also mean that there is no good answer available. It does not necessarily mean that what I'm trying to do is wrong.

Comment: Fetch them on the host into the dockerfile working directory.  Then build on the host, uploading them as part of the build context.  Your credentials never leave your machine, and it still builds on the dockerd host as usual.

Comment: You can't have it both ways; you either put the credentials into the build container so it can fetch them (you said you don't want this, but it is possible with `docker build --build-arg`), or you keep the credentials on your local machine and upload the cloned/downloaded code to the container (safer).  You have to pick one.

Comment: This is how the npm docs say to do it (which I found with two seconds of googling), but you're still putting your npm credentials into the container (it lives on in the history if the container isn't squashed, which is a major security risk that fails unsafe): https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/docker-and-private-modules

Comment: According to this issue, it looks like `npm pack` is the clientside command you're looking for: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2817